# ASP .Net Core, Cors Host vs Origin

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cors, builder

I am new to ASP .NET.
When I Wanted to add Cors, there were 2 options. `Host` and `Origin`.

What is the difference between them?

```
    builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("AllowOrigin", builder =>
        {
            builder
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true)
                .AllowCredentials();
            //or
            builder
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true)
            .AllowCredentials();
    
        });
    });
```

Comment: Parameter name :) which makes no functional difference.

Comment: `.SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true).AllowCredentials()` is insecure! Essentially, you're throwing the Same-Origin Policy out the window: you're allowing any Web origin to force an authenticated request and read its response. Instead, you should restrict the set of allowed origins to the bare minimum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are both identical.
`SetIsOriginAllowed` expects a function that takes a string and returns a boolean.
Both of those lambdas do that.
You can call the parameter "x" and it'll still be the same function.

Answer (score 1):

The method here is `.SetIsOriginAllowed(Func<bool,string>)`.

It's one method that takes a lambda with a string parameter that returns a bool. If you're not familiar with lambdas, they can be thought of as really terse inline functions.

In your question, `host` and `origin` are just different names for that string parameter, you could call it `TheSpanishInquisition` and it would still work identically. If you're not actually using that parameter, I'd suggest using the `_` discard operator, so it would be:

```cs
builder
  .AllowAnyMethod()
  .AllowAnyHeader()
  .SetIsOriginAllowed(_ => true)
  .AllowCredentials();
```

The different bracketisation doesn't matter either. Brackets around lambda parameters are optional if there's only a single parameter but are required if there are multiple.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the parameter any name you want.They is no difference

Comment: It would be better to explain why.